# vega-lite: How to break legend into multiple columns

Tags: vega-lite

Consider the following contrived example:

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower","type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Origin","type": "nominal"},
    "color": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon","type": "ordinal"}
  }
}
```

The dataset has many values for `Miles_per_Gallon` so the `color` legend will have many elements and will be considerably larger than the plot itself.

Is there a way to show this legend in multiple columns, rather than a single one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Miles per Gallon as a quantitative variable.

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower","type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Origin","type": "nominal"},
    "color": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon","type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```